# Turn off / on track changes vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

the code i have is working well. The issue i have is that i want to be **able to turn off and on track changes**. The reason being that , **not all users changes should be tracked**.All changes are recorded in a different sheet. Please see my code below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If ActiveSheet.Name = "TrackChanges_Record" Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False

UserName = Environ("USERNAME")

NewVal = Target.Value

Application.Undo

oldVal = Target.Value

lr = Sheets("TrackChanges_Record").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("TrackChanges_Record").Range("A" & lr) = Now
Sheets("TrackChanges_Record").Range("B" & lr) = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheets("TrackChanges_Record").Range("C" & lr) = Target.Address
Sheets("TrackChanges_Record").Range("D" & lr) = oldVal
Sheets("TrackChanges_Record").Range("E" & lr) = NewVal
Sheets("TrackChanges_Record").Range("F" & lr) = UserName

Target = NewVal

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: feel free to mark my answer as your solution if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If ActiveSheet.Name = "TrackChanges_Record" or Environ("USERNAME") = "UserToSkip1" or Environ("USERNAME") = "UserToSkip2" Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that code . I was hoping the user will have the option to turn off or on this code, i place above

Comment: i have restore to comments instead.

Comment: @James you can insert a messagebox which ask for turning on or off but then every user can deside by himself and you have no control